# Unable to render video with size greater than 640x640

Tags: ios, objective-c, render, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I am using `AVAssetExportSession` to export a video saved in my documents directory. I wish to apply a `CALayer` to the video and hence am using `AVMutableVideoComposition` and setting necessary `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction` and video exports fine.

My issue is, say the original video is of resolution 1920x1080 now when I export this video by setting the rendersize of the video composition to 1920x640 it gives me a video of size 640x360.

I tried setting the rendersize to smaller values like 300x300 where I get the resultant exported video of size 300x300 of course by cropping extra contents. I then tried setting the rendersixe to 700x700 it resulted into a 640x640 video.

What I could understand is that it maintains the aspect ratio as per the render size we set, hence when i set the size to 1920x1080 it gives a 630x360 video maintaining the ratin of 16:9. Similarly when i set the size to be 700x700 it results in a video of size 640x640 with aspect ratio 1:1.

The Problem

I want the video size to be the same as its original size. But when I set the size of the mutablevideoComposition to the naturalSize of the original videotrack it limits me to a size below 640x640(if the size is beyond 640x640).

Is this a known behaviour? or am I missing something. If it is a known behaviour is there another way wherein I can export the video at its original size or size greater than 640x640.

Help will be deeply appreicated. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Edit your question with code.

Comment: I realised I was looking at the wrong place for an issue all this while. Now that I realise it, it looks too simple of a mistake, a mistake nevertheless. The preset I was using to initialize the AVAssetExportSession was the cause of the issue. I have posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it. It was a simple mistake. I was initializing the export session with AVAssetExportPreset640x480 instead of AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the preset the `AVExportSession` maintains the aspect ratio of your video which is bigger then the preset in your case that is how you were getting a 640x360 when your video was 1920x1080 thereby maintaining the aspect ratio.